# How to match two fields of one row in PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am a code noob. I want to display a number from a mysql database based on the value of 2 dropdown boxes i.e

```
box a = 100
box b = 600
```

return value **36.50**

```
box a= 40
box b= 100
```

return value **125.95**

Please help with the php code.

Comment: how you decide to get return value what is?

Comment: are `a` and `b` fields?

Comment: a & b are static values from dropdown box return value is number they are linked too in mysql database

Comment: Please, what is the use of `a` and `b` ?

Comment: soooo box A would have values 1,2,3,4,5 box B would have values 1,2,3,4,5
selection of 1&1 would return linked value 1&2 would return different linked value and so on

Comment: Its for a price estimator. Box A is the number of pallets in store. box B is the different amounts of SKU's and i want it to return the price.

Comment: you want to get a value from database(price) whose pallets and SKU matches a and b?

Comment: Yes :D thats what i mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using MySQLi and not officially removed MySQL API.

Here is the Query:

```
$query = "SELECT price FROM database WHERE pallets = ? AND SKU = ?";

$stmt = $DB->prepare($query);

$stmt->bind_param("ii", $aValue, $bValue);

$stm->execute();

$stmt->get_result();

while($row = $stmt->fetch(MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
  echo "This is the price: " . $row['price'];
}
```

Note that your php version should at least be 5.4 for the above code to work.

`$aValue` and `$bValue` are respectively the value of two dropBoxes.

`"ii"` means respectively that values are of integer type.